# A purge script - saving and deleting files according to it date

Tags: python

I'm working on a purge script in Python. The following script is working fine. The script browse a list of directories and, according to each file date, remove or keep any files. So if any files exist after X days or minutes, these files are removed.

```
purge_files_path = ['x:/path/destination', 'x:/path/destination', ]

kwargs = {"weeks":0, "days": 0, "hours": 0, "minutes": 23}

def purge(purge_files_path, kwargs):

    import os
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    for folder in purge_files_path:
        for(dir, _, files) in os.walk(folder):
            for file in files:
                path = os.path.join(dir, file)

                if os.path.exists(path):
                    file_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path))
                    delta = datetime.now() - file_date

                    if delta >= timedelta(**kwargs):
                        os.remove(path)
```

Now, I just want to add a new functionality. I want, before to remove a file, to save it in another folder. It could be easy, but I want to keep the folder architecture of any files.

So if a file which has to be purged and located on:

```
c:/source/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

It has to be back up on :

```
c:/backup/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

I could use shutil.copytree, but I have an error of existing folders.

Comment: before you do shutil.copytree,  check whether that folder folder exist in the backup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `os.rename` instead of `os.remove`. You might want to use `relpath` to preserve directory structure. Just replace your call to `os.remove(path)` with the following snippet.

```
relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, folder))
backup_path = os.path.join(backup_dir, relative_path)
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(backup_path), exist_ok=True)
os.rename(path, backup_path)
```

Note: If the directories are on different volumes, you need to use `shutil.move` instead of `os.rename`.

To get python 2 support, you need to drop the `exists_ok=True` like so

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(backup_path)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(backup_path))
```

Comment: Is ""exist_ok=True"" compatible with Python 2 ?

Comment: It is not. You need to use and if statement to check if you need to create the directory

Comment: Thank you for your advices @vidstige